# React passing component with props and decorate it

Tags: reactjs, components

i have a react component:

```
<Camera onRecordButton={<Button text="My button Label">}>
```

Inside Camera.js i need to take my Button component and attach some other props.
I have tried with Render Props pattern and HOC but nothing i receive this error

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

inside my Camera.js i have:

```
...
{withProps(onRecordButton)}
...
```

and withProps is:

```
const Dismiss = ({ children }) => {
    const dismiss = () => {
      console.log('Click')
    }
  
    return children(dismiss)
  }

const withProps = (Component) =>
  (props) => (
    <Dismiss>
      {(dismiss) => (
        <Component onClick={dismiss} {...props} />
      )}
    </Dismiss>
  )

  export default withProps;
```

I have no ideas what's wrong... any ideas?

***UPDATE***

Thx sambomartin but it doesn't work,

I'am passing my component like this:

```
<Camera className="py-5 relative" recordbutton={<Button text="Testo" />} />
```

and this is the error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2560 string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Button />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

Seem that the problem is in Camera.js and a method with i pass compoment to enhance down to child:

```
// Make.js

import Camera from './Camera'
import Button from "../Button/Button";


const Make = () => {

    const {prevStep} = useProgress()

    return (
        <>
      // it work's
      <Camera className="py-5 relative" recordbutton={Button} />

      // NOT  work's
      <Camera className="py-5 relative" recordbutton={<Button text="help!" />} />



            
        </>
    )

}
 
export default Make;
```

If i pass as  not working, i don't understand

here an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hoc-ksjbf

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct / destruct props correctly.  In your example, you were passing the function is the props.

```
const Dismiss = ({ children }) => {
const dismiss = () => {
  console.log('Click')
}

return children( {dismiss} )
}

const withProps = (Component) =>
  (props) => (
    <Dismiss>
      {({dismiss}) => (
        <Component onClick={dismiss} {...props} />
      )}
    </Dismiss>
  )

  export default withProps;
```

Comment: Thx sambomartin but it doesent work, please check my answer update ;)